# Prepending to module that gets included/extended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prepend, alias-method-chain

I'm moving from using `Module#alias_method_chain` to `Module#prepend`.

But there is one situation where I cannot achieve the same functionality

Suppose I have a library code (two libraries actually, one of which enhances another)

```
# Library 1
object = Object.new
# Library 2
module Extender
  def random_number
    4
  end
end
object.extend Extender

object.random_number # => 4
```

Now, say I want `object#random_number` to return 5. My old code was

```
Extender.class_eval do
  def random_number_with_magic
    random_number_without_magic + 1
  end
  alias_method_chain :random_number, :magic
end

object.random_number # => 5
```

To mimic this using `Module#prepend`

```
module Prepender
  def random_number
    super + 1
  end
end
Extender.prepend Prepender

object.random_nuber # => still 4!
```

The desired results could be achieved by two approaches

- call `Extender.prepend Prepender` **before** `object.extend Extender` (not an option since I cannot control the code in external libraries)
- call `object.extend Prepender` **instead** of `Extender.prepend Prepender` (not an option since `object` object is not visible outside)

Any advice?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ there are no “invisible outside” objects in ruby.

Comment: riight. what i meant to say was 'easily visible' =) besides in this particular situation several similar objects end up in an array, and there's no easy way to distinguish between them and choose the right one to extend